# Java program as a Windows Service

Tags: windows, java

I create a Java server, which tools do you recommend to wrap java as a Windows service?

Is it possible to have the service launch in sequence? Say server is start before a Java client can be run?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have the service
>   launch in sequence? Say server is
>   start before a Java client can be run?

Yes. No. Services can have a sequence (depend on other services). How the heck, though, do you want to stop a user starting a client ON ANOTHER COMPUTER? This is like stopping people from typing your website address in the browser when you maintain your server. Does not work.

For the rest google is really your friend. "Windows Service Java" got me three hits - different wrappers - on the first page, the first three items.

http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/32068

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app (whow, even here - try search here before posting)

http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp

I will stop here. The list goes on and on and on and on. Google really is nice to find trivial things like that.

Answer (score 0):

> I create a Java server, which tools do you recommend to wrap java as a Windows service?

Yes. It's been covered by TomTom answers (google: "Java as Windows Service").

> Is it possible to have the service launch in sequence? Say server is start before a Java client can be run?

You can't ensure clients running on other machine to run only after the server started.

However your client application can be made to wait until the server (I assume it's a TCP/IP server) listening to the TCP/IP port. So in order to achieve this, the client should itself wait until the server is up.